# Use Guice Injection in a Java GAE Backend Servlet

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, guice, guice-servlet, sitebricks

I have a dilemma in my GAE Java app: I am trying to write a servlet that will be handled by GAE backends **and** it must also use *Guice dependency injection* to initiate all the servlet's fields. I have tried multiple approaches but none seems to be doing the trick for me.

I first tried to use **Sitebricks** in the servlet, but it seemed that doing so results in GAE being unable to detect the class as a legit servlet when the backend URL is being queried: a *404 Not Found* is always returned from the backend. Despite this, I know for sure that the class is annotated correctly with Sitebricks annotations because the same URI path works fine with the frontend instance.

Next, I tried to use **Guice Servlet Extension** (see [this link](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule)); in my class that creates the global `Injector`, I used this binding:

```
return Guice.createInjector(..., new ServletModule() {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        serve("/backend/*").with(MyBackend.class);
    }
}, ...);
```

Unfortunately, the same exact issue as with Sitebricks happens: I am returned a 404 error on the backend but not on the frontend.

The last feasible approach would be to configure the servlet-mapping in `web.xml`; the traditional approach. This finally allows my backend to detect the URI mapping (which follows along with what is writen in [Google's documentation of Java GAE backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview): *"Backends share the servlets defined in web.xml with the main application version."*). Unfortunately, I would not be able to take advantage of Guice injection using this procedure and hence it is extremely undesirable for me to use `web.xml`.

I even tried combining the second and third approach: use both the Guice Servlet Extension and web.xml. This resuled in a 500 error being returned from the backend with this error:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.MyBackend
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doRedirectedServerRequest(BackendServersFilter.java:292)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServers.forwardToServer(BackendServers.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doServerRedirect(BackendServersFilter.java:237)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:100)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

20-Dec-2012 3:23:53 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: /backend/example/rest/call
java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.MyBackend
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:340)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doRedirectedServerRequest(BackendServersFilter.java:292)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:106)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServers.forwardToServer(BackendServers.java:56)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doServerRedirect(BackendServersFilter.java:237)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:100)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

One final thing to note: I configured my *backends.xml* file to have `<public>true</public>`, but I am testing these HTTP request calls by querying the backend from the frontend of my GAE app. Also, note that my frontend instance is properly retrieving the backend address using `BackendService` ([javadoc here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/backends/BackendService)).

#### Other related Stackoverflow questions I have asked before

- [Is Sitebricks compatible with GAE backends (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964043/is-sitebricks-compatible-with-gae-backends-java)
- [Sitebricks and Channel Presence Service (GAE); Also having trouble with normal servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924170/sitebricks-and-channel-presence-service-gae-also-having-trouble-with-normal-s)

Comment: Are you handling the /_ah/start/ call in your code? The backend will not serve any requests until it gets a 200 OK response from the /_ah/start/ call.

Comment: Yes I have...issue is beyond /_ah/start

Comment: @ecbrodie Have you found a solution?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately I am no longer working on this project, so I cannot tell whether the development team found a solution or not. Looks like this issue is still hot in the world, hopefully someone can post an answer sooner than later.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems to be due to the fact that App Engine Backends completely ignores filters in web.xml. 

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=9859

Answer (score 1):

[Backends have been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends) in favor of [Modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/).

I'm working on some sample code using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) w/ Guice, it's still in progress (I haven't started pruning things yet), but here are some excerpts.

from pom.xml:

```
<!-- [START Guice] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- [END Guice] -->
<!-- [START Jersey] -->
        <!-- Jersey -->
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
          <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
          <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
          <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
          <artifactId>guice-bridge</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0</version>
      </dependency>
<!-- [END Jersey] -->
```

from JerseyConfiguration.java:

```
public class JerseyConfiguration extends ResourceConfig {
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Inject
    public JerseyConfiguration(ServiceLocator serviceLocator, ServletContext servletContext) {
        log.info("Creating JerseyConfiguration");
        packages("com.example.gettingstarted");

        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(serviceLocator);
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = serviceLocator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector((Injector) servletContext.getAttribute(Injector.class.getName()));
    }
}
```

From GettingStartedServletContextListener:

```
public class GettingStartedServletContextListener extends
        GuiceServletContextListener {

    @Override
    protected Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(new GettingStartedModule());
    }
}
```

From GettingStartedModule.java:

```
public class GettingStartedModule extends ServletModule {

  @Override
  protected void configureServlets() {
      serve("/hi").with(HelloWorldServlet.class);
  }
}
```

From HelloWorldServlet.java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Singleton
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
      resp.setContentType("text/plain");
      resp.getWriter().println("Hello, old friend");
  }
}
```